# Optimizing INNER JOIN across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have trawled many of the similar responses on this site and have improved my code at several stages along the way. Unfortunately, this 3-row query still won't run.

I have one table with 100k+ rows and about 30 columns of which I can filter down to 3-rows (in this example) and then perform `INNER JOIN`s across 21 small lookup tables.

In my first attempt, I was lazy and used implicit joins.

```
SELECT `master_table`.*, `lookup_table`.`data_point` x 21
FROM `lookup_table` x 21
WHERE `master_table`.`indexed_col` = "value"
AND `lookup_table`.`id` = `lookup_col` x 21
```

The query looked to be timing out:

`#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Following this, I tried being explicit about the joins.

```
SELECT `master_table`.*, `lookup_table`.`data_point` x 21
FROM `master_table`
INNER JOIN `lookup_table` ON `lookup_table`.`id` = `master_table`.`lookup_col` x 21
WHERE `master_table`.`indexed_col` = "value"
```

Still got the same result. I then realised that the query was probably trying to perform the joins first, then filter down via the `WHERE` clause. So after a bit more research, I learned how I could apply a subquery to perform the filter first and then perform the joins on the newly created table. This is where I got to, and it still returns the same error. Is there any way I can improve this query further?

```
SELECT `temp_table`.*, `lookup_table`.`data_point` x 21
FROM (SELECT * FROM `master_table` WHERE `indexed_col` = "value") as `temp_table`
INNER JOIN `lookup_table` ON `lookup_table`.`id` = `temp_table`.`lookup_col` x 21
```

Is this the best way to write up this kind of query? I tested the subquery to ensure it only returns a small table and can confirm that it returns only three rows.

Comment: You can use EXPLAIN before query to get a more detailed execution plan. In my experience, it's very unusual that the optimizer will prioritize an unquantified join over a scalar lookup (even if no index and doing a FTS). So, are you sure you have not oversimplified your example thus also hiding the source of the weirdness?

Comment: It's possible. All of the lookups are to the primary key, there is one occasion where the lookup table is used twice, there is also a couple of occasions where I get two columns from a lookup table rather than one. Other than that, it's in the exact form as described above.

Comment: **Conceptually**, SQL applies WHERE conditions after joins, but in reality, most RDBMS (MySQL included) are smart enough to apply (at least some) WHERE conditions when doing so will not change the final result.

Comment: I am stepping through each of the 21 joins, adding one at a time using the format of the second attempt to see if I can find out when it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, at its most simple aspect you are looking for

```
select
      mt.*
   from
      Master_Table mt
   where
      mt.indexed_col = 'value'
```

That is probably instantaneous provided you have an index on your master table on the given indexed_col in the first position (in case you had a compound index of many fields)…

Now, if I am understanding you correctly on your different lookup columns (21 in total), you have just simplified them for redundancy in this post, but actually doing something in the effect of

```
select
      mt.*,
      lt1.lookupDescription1,
      lt2.lookupDescription2,
      ...
      lt21.lookupDescription21
   from
      Master_Table mt
         JOIN Lookup_Table1 lt1
            on mt.lookup_col1 = lt1.pk_col1
         JOIN Lookup_Table2 lt2
            on mt.lookup_col2 = lt2.pk_col2
         ...
         JOIN Lookup_Table21 lt21
            on mt.lookup_col21 = lt21.pk_col21
   where
      mt.indexed_col = 'value'
```

I had a project well over a decade ago dealing with a similar situation... the Master table had about 21+ million records and had to join to about 30+ lookup tables.  The system crawled and queried died after running a query after more than 24 hrs.

This too was on a MySQL server and the fix was a single MySQL keyword...

```
Select STRAIGHT_JOIN mt.*, ...
```

By having your master table in the primary position, where clause and its criteria directly on the master table, you are good.  You know the relationships of the tables.  Do the query in the exact order I presented it to you.  Don't try to think for me on this and try to optimize based on a subsidiary table that may have smaller record count and somehow think that will help the query faster... it won't.

Try the STRAIGHT_JOIN keyword.  It took the query I was working on and finished it in about 1.5 hrs... it was returning all 21 million rows with all corresponding lookup key descriptions for final output, hence still needed a longer duration than just 3 records.

Comment: The query now ran in 0.75 seconds. That is a massive performance boost!

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use a subquery.  Write the query as:

```
SELECT mt.*, lt.`data_point`
FROM `master_table` mt INNER JOIN
     `lookup_table` l
     ON l.`id` = mt.`lookup_col`
WHERE mt.`indexed_col` = value;
```

The indexes that you want are `master_table(value, lookup_col)` and `lookup_table(id, data_point)`.

If you are still having performance problems, then there are multiple possibilities.  High among them is that the result set is simply too big to return in a reasonable amount of time.  To see if that is the case, you can use `select count(*)` to count the number of returned rows.

Comment: This was the format my second attempt got me before using a subquery. Can you provide a reason for why a subquery is a bad idea?

As mentioned in the question body, the query only returns 3 rows in my test case. This was confirmed by `SELECT COUNT(*)`. Looking at your query syntax, will this not result in the `JOIN` occurring ahead of the `WHERE` clause being acted upon. If that's the case, the join operation will need to occur 100,000+ times before filtering down to the three-row result?

Comment: @MowgliB https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14565/mysql-subquery-slows-down-drastically-but-they-work-fine-independently

Comment: @MowgliB see my comment to the original question as to why the WHERE still gets handled first without a subquery. As far as why you should not be using a subquery in this case; if you have the indexes Gordon pointed out, the subquery will prevent the outer query from using the indexes of the subqueried tables.

Comment: @MowgliB . . . SQL is a *declarative* language, not a *procedural* language.  The optimizer determines the best execution method for the query.